# Joint Density of Independent and Uniform Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

I was able to calculate the density of the $XY$. My attempt went like this:  if we consider the intervals in which $X$ and $Y$ are equal to $1$ $(0 < x,y < 1)$ then the density of $XY$ is $1$ when $0 < xy < 1$ and $0$ for all other values of $xy$. Finding the cdf from this was much trickier however, I realize that you have to integrate the density, but I'm not sure with respect to what.

For $X/Y$, it is much trickier to calculate the density because there are several cases we have to consider. $Y$ cannot equal $0$ otherwise $X/Y$ is undefined (would this be written as $f(X/Y) = 0$ if $Y = 0$)? This second part is much more confusing, so I need help finding both the cdf and pdf of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to worry about $Y=0$, or any other particular value of $Y$, as particular values have probability zero.

The cdf of $X/Y$ is given by $$F(z)=P(X/Y\le z) = P(X\le zY)=\iint_{x\le zy} dx\,dy$$
and then the pdf is the derivative $F'(z)$.

Comment: Ahh that's a relief, I was computing different cases for which x/y was 0 and 1! What would the cdf of F(XY) happen to be by that reasoning?

Comment: Well then you integrate over the region where $xy\le z$ instead